# building wso2 from source - mvn eclipse:eclipse from which folder?

Tags: wso2

I'm looking through some [instructions](http://docs.wso2.org/display/BPS310/Building+from+Source#BuildingfromSource-directory) for building a WSO2 product from source.

The instructions state that `mvn clean install` is to be performed from the folder `<local-platform-directory>/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/turing-chunk05/product-releases/chunk-05`

`mvn eclipse:eclipse` can then be peformed, but from which directory?

Should `mvn elipse:eclipse` be performed from:

- `<local-platform-directory>` (the top level source folder), or
- `<local-platform-directory>/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/turing-chunk05/product-releases/chunk-05` (the folder from which you performed mvn clean install)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run `mvn elipse:eclipse` in any directory with a Maven `pom.xml`

I think you already know the structure of the WSO2 platform. For example, turing platform has following structure.

- build/
- components/
- dependencies/
- features/
- parent/
- platform-integration/
- product-releases/
- products/
- samples/
- service-stubs/

When you use `<local-platform-directory>`, the top level source directory, you will get all modules references by the root [pom.xml](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/turing-chunk05/pom.xml).

When you use `<local-platform-directory>/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/turing-chunk05/product-releases/chunk-05/`, the source directory for chunk-05 release, you will get all modules referenced by the chunk-05 [pom.xml](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/turing-chunk05/product-releases/chunk-05/pom.xml).

If you go through the chunk-05 release pom.xml and sub module pom.xml files, you will see that it just builds the relevant components, dependencies, features, products etc.

If you want to build the chunk-05 release, you must build from chunk-05 [pom.xml](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/turing-chunk05/product-releases/chunk-05/pom.xml), which will build all released maven projects with chunk-05.

The wiki doc just explains the commands to get a maven project to your IDE. i.e. Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA.

So, I would recommend you to open only the required Maven projects. I usually use the Eclipse to edit the code only and most of the real code is in `components` and `dependencies`. For other directories, editing pom.xml via a text editor is enough for me.

If you want to patch any component in chunk-05 release, you can use chunk-05 [pom.xml](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/turing-chunk05/product-releases/chunk-05/pom.xml) and sub modules to identify relevant Maven project.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks again Isuru!  I think I will `mvn eclipse:eclipse` only the products that I'm interested in rather than the top level source directory.  Thanks also for the tip that the real 'meat' is in `components` and `dependencies`.

Comment: Great. Features usually wrap `components` and `dependencies`. And I think you know that a WSO2 Product is WSO2 Carbon + Set of features. So, all the features are inside the root level `features` directory.

Comment: When I get some time, I plan to document (in the stratos developers guide) the relationships and meanings of 'components', 'dependencies', 'features', 'products' and 'distributions' - unless that documentation already exists elsewhere?  I think this is knowledge is key for anyone working on carbon based products?